# Create edges between nodes of the same class using SQL

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have inserted a number of vertices of class "People" and I would like to create edges between those who live in the same City. These vertices are not yet connected with each other with any type of edge.

I believe one way to do would be, using (standard) SQL, somehow like this:

```
CREATE EDGE SameCity FROM (SELECT From People) A TO (SELECT FROM People) B WHERE A.@rid<>B.@rid AND A.city=B.city;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, since subquery names don't work with OrientDB SQL.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to get all people living in the same city you could slightly modify your data structure in favor of this:

```
----------    livesIn      --------
| People |  ----------->   | City |
----------                 --------
```

---

I've created a small data example:

```
create class people extends v
create property people.name string
create class city extends v
create property city.name string

create class livesIn extends e


create vertex people set name="pippo"
create vertex people set name="gigi"
create vertex people set name="pluto"

create vertex city set name="bergamo"
create vertex city set name="grassobbio"

create edge livesIn from (select from people where name = "pippo") to (select from city where name = "bergamo")
create edge livesIn from (select from people where name = "gigi") to (select from city where name = "grassobbio")
create edge livesIn from (select from people where name = "pluto") to (select from city where name = "bergamo")
```

[image: screenshot]

then you can obtain all people, e.g., living in Bergamo you can do it with

```
select in("livesIn") from city where name = "bergamo"
```

or

```
select in("livesIn").name from city where name = "bergamo" unwind in
```

---

Hope it helps. 
Ivan

Comment: Thank you Ivan but I'd rather not create a new class; this property (city) is not so important.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did it after I read this post:
[OrientDB - Create Edge using kind of self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507054/orientdb-create-edge-using-kind-of-self-join?rq=1)

However I am not sure whether this is the fastest way to do it (compared to SQL), but it worked, so I am going to leave it like this for now.

EDIT:
This solution though requires bringing all nodes into memory, which is not efficient (I am going to have several millions of nodes and edges are going to be even more). With SQL it would be a lot more efficient also because of indexes.
So if there is another suggestion I would be really grateful!